# Tag synonym proposal [truetype] --> [ttf] on Stack Overflow is stuck

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

`[ttf]` is already mapped to `[true-type-fonts]`, however there is also a proposal of `[truetype]` to `[ttf]` (-1).

Since the search now auto-replaces `[ttf]` with the master tag, you can no longer get to the synonym voting page.

Can I get a mod to dump this proposal (I was trying to downvote it anyway), and add the following as synonyms of `[true-type-fonts]`:

`[truetype]` (3)
`[true-type-font]` (0)

(Even for mods, do tags have to exist in the system for them to be added as synonyms? This can easily be circumvented, but I'm curious.)

Comment: In the future, the system should probably handle this automatically

Comment: A related problem here is that you can't take back a proposal. I suggested [truetype] -> [ttf] only to then realize that there is also a [true-type-font]. But then it's too late to change ones mind about the first proposal. [Comments on the synonym proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60485/please-allow-comments-on-tag-synonym-proposals) could help here, since you could say "please vote down, should be ... instead".

Comment: @sth: Yes, agreed, although in this case comments wouldn't help because you can't get to the synonym page.

Answer (score 1):

(Bump)

Another situation where the synonym proposal is stuck is when the master tag is deleted, as the page now 404s. e.g.

- [`[programming]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/programming/synonyms) × 0 ← [`[programmability]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically) × 0
- [`[perl-lwp]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl-lwp/synonyms) × 0 ← [`[lwp]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lwp) × 31