# Please allow comments on tag synonym proposals

Tags: feature-request, comments, tag-synonyms

I've downvoted quite a few proposals because I thought the synonym should go the other way, or I disagreed with the proposal outright, but I felt like I should say something about why I think that way in many of the cases. (For example, there is currently proposed `[ce]` --> `[windows-ce]` on Stack Overflow.)

It would much more robust, relevant, and economical to allow comments for each synonym proposal right on that page, as opposed to starting a new discussion question on Meta for every single one, where it wouldn't necessarily get exposure anyway.

---

While it's possible that a discussion on a synonym may end up lengthy, there could be a facility where if the number of comments reach a certain threshold (10 sounds like a good number), then all the comments are removed and migrated to the appropriate Meta in the form of a question (with a link left behind) -- the synonym proposer would own the question (probably best to auto-set it CW), and all comments would end up as comments on the question. (I realize the migration system may be too much effort for a small gain, but it's one solution to the problem.)

Answer (score 3):

This to me sound like a big can of worms.

So we enable commenting ... next we need to port the flagging system to watch those comments and the whole moderation piece around it. Then people are going to want comment voting and so on as well. You already mentioned a migration piece as well.

A better approach imho is to educate our moderators to work through the lists and nuke / approve / merge.

Comment: Hmm... good points. Although similar stuff is planned for the tag wikis, right?

Comment: @Jon sure we really wan tag wikis to be a new post type

Comment: That makes sense. What about doing the same for synonym proposals? The structure is already there and for my migration suggestion, that system is already in place, too! That would actually work out pretty nicely.

Comment: I agree that the mods could help out, but they already have enough stuff to do. Particularly on SO where it's a very long list, it's also possible that not all of the topics may get covered by mod knowledge.

Comment: I agree with the slogan "Keep it Simple", but yesterday a proposal to add "xsltprocessor" to the list of "xslt" synonyms was rejected. Because there was no discuss here in Meta, I took the discussion to chat before rejecting the proposal. Today, the proposal was again made. How can this user to take into account the discussion already made before making her/his proposal? How can record their reasons? There should be a requirement to start a discussion on Meta?

Answer (score 3):

While I think we definitely need comments on the synonym sub-pages of the particular tag pages, and was preparing a feature-request when I saw this one, I think the real answer is to automatically generate a post on Meta and link to it.

An alternative to this would be to let someone create a Meta post if they wanted to, and then to allow that person to link to it from the synonym sub-page.

Comment: +1 Good idea -- I think this might take the form of a "Discuss" button or something to auto-generate a Meta post and link, since most of the synonyms don't need discussion. All of that kind of plumbing shouldn't need user input aside from the ability to start the discussion.