# How to handle reverse synonyms?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Currently there's a [tag synonym for jquery1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery1.4/synonyms), however it's backwards from every other version convention, it should be:

- jQuery1.4 -> jquery-1.4

However it's currently reversed, can we get this...reversed?  It's backwards from the rest of the system with respect to the `tag-version` format.

Related: [How should versioned jQuery tags be combined on stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57489)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, the best thing to do is post a request on Meta to get it fixed.

I've [proposed to allow comments on tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60485/please-allow-comments-on-tag-synonym-proposals), which may avoid having these synonyms go through in the first place.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have the choice in which direction the synonym should be proposed, so you anyway need to ask on meta for moderator intervention if you want to get it fixed. Comments on synonyms won't really help there. You can comment that the synonym should be the other way around, but unless a moderator comes by and sees it by chance, nobody can do anything about it. Maybe it should be possible to flag synonym suggestions for moderator attention?

Comment: @sth: Agreed on the flagging. There are, of course, a lot of ways that kind of mod notification could be implemented. It's difficult to have the system pick out these types of "invalid" synonyms. Perhaps slightly different rules would help: right now you can't go from big tag to small tag, but what if there was only a restriction on the *ratio* of the two tags. So you couldn't propose 2,000 --> 1, but you could propose, say, 2,000 --> 500.

Comment: You should totally drop what you're doing and use meta!